# How to avoid iteration though pandas df and apply affect on multiple columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop

My df is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1": ["AA", "BB", np.nan, np.nan, "CC"],
    "col2": ["XYZ", "TEST", "123A", "JOHN", "DOE"],
    "col3": list(range(1,6)),
    "col4": [5, 4, 10, 2, 1],
    "col5": ["str1", "str2", np.nan, "str3", np.nan],
    "col6": ["test1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5"]
})
```

Now, if cells of first column are equels to null, I want to apply values from col2 to col1 and accordingly - from col4 to col3 and from col6 to col5.

My only idea is to achieve that using for loop:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
     if pd.isnull(df['col1'][i]):
            df['col1'][i] = df['col2'][i]
            df['col3'][i] = df['col4'][i]
            df['col5'][i] = df['col6'][i]
```

But in case of real-world-data it takes to long time and I am looking for a idea how to do that without using for loop, just more "pandasic" way.

Any hints are appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example can work with `bfill`:

```
m = df['col1'].isna()
df[m] = df[m].bfill(axis=1).values
print(df)

# Output
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5   col6
0    AA   XYZ     1     5  str1  test1
1    BB  TEST     2     4  str2     t2
2  123A  123A     3    10    t3     t3
3  JOHN  JOHN     4     2  str3     t4
4    CC   DOE     5     1   NaN     t5
```

Comment: No, it will fill col5 index 4, but you can fix it with slicing, ordering of the columns and `update`.

Comment: `df.update(df.loc[df['col1'].isnull(), ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6']].bfill(axis=1))` and it will fail if you have NaNs in the cols 2/4/6

Answer (score 3):

Using a mask for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with conversion [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html):

```
m = df['col1'].isnull()

df.loc[m, ['col1', 'col3', 'col5']] = (df.loc[m, ['col2', 'col4', 'col6']]
                                         .to_numpy()
                                      )
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5   col6
0    AA   XYZ     1     5  str1  test1
1    BB  TEST     2     4  str2     t2
2  123A  123A    10    10    t3     t3
3  JOHN  JOHN     2     2    t4     t4
4    CC   DOE     5     1   NaN     t5
```